# Windows 8 can't print from Internet Explorer but can print from other programs

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer, printing

I have a machine running Windows 8. When we try to print a bank statement, a side bar pops up asking which printer to select. After selecting the printer I get a message stating it couldn't connect to the printer. Also, when trying to print a web page by using the right-click context menu, it says:

```
Internet Explorer has stopped working
```

When printing from any other program, such as Outlook or Word, the usual print window pops up and it prints without any problem to the same printer.

Any ideas what's causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: What is the version of internet explorer is it internet explorer 10

Comment: Can you describe the *side bar* you're getting in more detail, perhaps even provide a screen shot?  What happens when you print from Internet Explorer using the keyboard shortcut `CTRL+P`?

Comment: Vembu: it's I.E. 11.  Twisty: I don't have access to the computer right now, but the side bar slid in from the right side and was like the Windows 8 app layout.

Answer (score 0):

Is that you are having two links labeled like this: Inter Explorer (64-bit), and Internet Explorer. If you are having two icons of internet explorer like 64 and unlabelled one then try using the internet explorer 32 and check whether you are able to print the page you wanted.

Same issue has been discussed in Microsoft forum. but yet it don't have proper fix than role back to older version.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie10-windows_7/printing-problems-in-internet-explorer-10/c88957c1-0fd4-42c8-ba5f-a14acb7c62ff